# Share 3D objects in a city and have people see them with ARKit

Tags: ios, arkit

I’m looking for something that lets people place 3D objects around a city and have people see them exactly where they were placed, even with years apart. I’m looking for something more asynchronous than a real-time experience so [ARWorldMap](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldmap) is out of the equation. [Google Cloud Anchors](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/) does not work with provided GPS coordinates either. I've looked into [`.gravityAndWorldMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration/worldalignment/gravityandheading), how can I use it? Is this project something feasible with ARKit?

Answer (score 0):

Try Sturfee, works on top of ARKit. Only available from within Unity and some cities.

https://sturfee.com/